# Convolution of Haar filter

Tags: signal-processing

In "Conceptual Wavelets" (2009) by D. Lee Fugal, on pg 47 he writes

```
Conv ([-1, 1], [1, 1]) = [-1, 2,-1]
```

When I do it I get

```
0    -1    1    0
1     1                           > -1
       1.   1.                   > 0
             1     1.            > 1
```

So I get [-1, 0, 1]. What am I not understanding?

The definition Fugal is using is the Matlab function conv which I assume is just traditional convolution....

Comment: Write down the author's actual definition of the `Conv()` function over finite sequences.  Also, give us a proper reference (author's name, book title, year of publication, page).  Perhaps it's a typo in a book, perhaps not.  But there's no way to know from your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the book is really using Matlab's `conv` then it must be a typo.

Bring up Matlab and try it.  (Or if you don't have Matlab then go to octave-online.net and try it.)

The [Matlab definition of `conv` over finite sequences](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/conv.html) also agrees with your answer.

Comment: Hm not sure this answer ("use Matlab") is suitable for this site.  Of course, typos rarely allow good answers.

Comment: I agree, on both counts.  Perhaps I should just make my answer into a comment.  Or did you mean I should actually transcribe the definition of `conv` and show that OP's result is correct (even though he calculated it by padding with zeros, which is not the normal way of dealing with the boundary conditions)?

Comment: I'd say your comment on the question needs to be addressed before any more effort is warranted. Then, we are at a "check my answer" impasse, a "good" answer to which would effectively reproduce the calculation and then answer "yes". So nah, not going to advice this.

Comment: OP did address my comment on the question.  The original question had no reference and didn't give any definition of `conv` whatsoever.  I agree, it's a "check my answer" question (and related to a language and a topic that would probably have been better addressed by dsp.se or scicomp.se.)